# Bot Framework - Open Task Module From Hero Card

Tags: c#, botframework, chatbot, microsoft-teams

I am in the process of trying to learn the bot framework following along with documentation and sample code. I currently have a bot that, when messaged, will return a Hero Card that contains an 'invoke' card action to enter a task module.

```
private Attachment GetTaskModuleHeroCard()
        {
            return new HeroCard()
            {
                Title = "Task Module Invocation from Hero Card",
                Subtitle = "This is a hero card with a Task Module Action button.",
                Buttons = new List<CardAction>()
                    {

                        new CardAction()
                         {
                                Type = "invoke",
                                Title = "Task Module Invocation from Hero Card",
                                Value = "{\"type\": \"task/fetch\", \"data\": \"fake data\"}"
                         }
                    },
            }.ToAttachment();
        }
```

The Hero Card shows up fine in both the teams desktop app and the web app. When I click the button, the following code runs, which I believe means that the invoke/fetch action was a success

```
protected override async Task<TaskModuleResponse> OnTeamsTaskModuleFetchAsync(ITurnContext<IInvokeActivity> turnContext, TaskModuleRequest taskModuleRequest, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {      
            return new TaskModuleResponse
            {
                Task = new TaskModuleContinueResponse
                {
                    Value = new TaskModuleTaskInfo
                    {
                        Url = "https://[mywebapp].azurewebsites.net/",
                        Title = "Test",
                        Height = "medium",
                        Width = "medium",
                        FallbackUrl = "https://[mywebapp].azurewebsites.net/"
                    }
                }
            };
        }
```

At this point a modal will open with my 'Title' field displayed, but the remainder of the modal will be blank. In the browser console I am given the error "2020-02-10T19:17:48.800Z AppsService: getInstalledAppForUser - Invalid appId specified." In both the Bot project's appsettings.json and the manifest I have the Microsoft App ID of my Azure Bot Channel Registration's settings. The appsettings.json contains the generated secret as well. I am hosting the bot with IIS and tunneling to it with ngrok. The messaging endpoint is "https://[myngrok].ngrok.io/api/messages." The html page I am trying to iframe is hosted on Azure and I am capable of reaching it through my local machine as well as other machines. It is a youtube embed iframe. The domain of the web app is also included in the validDomains array of the manifest. Does anyone see anything I am doing wrong?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Could you please try putting a debugger and see if the task module response you are sending has an issue. Here is how the response should look like: 
{
  "task": {
    "type": "continue",
    "value": {
      "title": "Task module title",
      "height": 500,
      "width": "medium",
      "url": "https://contoso.com/msteams/taskmodules/newcustomer",
      "fallbackUrl": "https://contoso.com/msteams/taskmodules/newcustomer"
    }
  }
}

Comment: @Gousia-MSFT Here is the response I send to teams `{"task":{"value":{"title":"Test","height":"medium","width":"medium","url":"https://[mywebapp].azurewebsites.net","card":null,"fallbackUrl":"https://google.com","completionBotId":null},"type":"continue"}} ` I am capable of debugging my code up to the point where I send back the TaskModuleResponse. The json object I provided in this comment is the result of JsonConvert.SerializeObject(). Is this the right approach to determine what I am sending back? Or is there a better way?

Comment: The response looks fine. Could you please confirm whether the page you are trying to load inside Task Module is iframable? Please add a screenshot of the error you are seeing.